# spring xml files and import xml files circular dependencies

Tags: spring, circular-dependency

It seems that you can do this in spring

```
file A.xml imports B.xml
file B.xml imports C.xml
file C.xml imports A.xml or B.xml
```

This is really killing our project as the dependencies between the xml files are messed up and when you only want to pull in one file it tends to pull in all this other junk.  Is there any way in spring to prevent this circular dependency stuff so it blows up on startup?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Any insight on this? Our tests have circular dependencies and for whatever reason each transaction with our database turns into two transactions with our database.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something similar was flagged many years ago but has not yet been implemented: [SPR-1142](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1142).